# Restrict External access to Specific branches from an Azure Devops Repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have several repositories in my Azure DevOps organization.
I want to Restrict external users' access to Specific branches from a repository.
I have checked repository security as well as branch security, but unable to figure a way around.
Looking for help.

Created a group and added a user.
Provided reader access to the project containing the repository.
Removed reader access to all the branches under the repository.
The user was still able to access all the branches of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git permissions do not support read restrictions on the branch level. For external users, you may:

1. Fork your main repo: [Forks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)
2. Deny access to the main repo for your external users.

Comment: Alright. But there is Branch security under Repos ->> branches ->> branch security.
So, what specific use case can be rendered with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the ability of users to contribute to a specific Git branch and modify it through Azure DevOps, but you can't restrict their ability to see and individual branch and pull it.

[Branch security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops) also allows you to restrict some behavior on pushes, pull requests, and bypassing branch policies set up in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Okay. how do I achieve this at least?

Comment: I had linked a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this with the link in answer I provided:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops